# date.timezone = PRC didn't work in php.ini file

Tags: php

I used the function `date()` to get the time, but I found the result to be incorrect (8 hours less than the time on my PC).

I checked the *php.ini* file and found that `date.timezone = Asia/Shanghai`.
So I updated it with `date.timezone = PRC` and restarted Apache, but it didn't fix it. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What do you mean by "found it incorrect"? You'll want to be a little bit more specific about 1) the expected behavior is and 2) the actual outcome. Maybe post an example as well. This will help others reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are you getting UTC by default? Perhaps PRC is a valid value but I did not find it in http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.

Comment: Yes, I found the default timezone is UTC by `phpinfo()`. But PRC is in [http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)  and I use function `date_default_timezone_set('PRC')` can set the default timezone to PRC. Why it can't set in php.ini.